# How to make sure a superclass object is not null

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I have two classes, one being the subclass of another. I want to make it so that the superclass can do its original methods even if the actual object is an instance of the subclass.

The below code prints *hello null* and then outputs the error: `Cannot invoke "A.doThis()" because "this.object" is null`

```
public class A {
  A object;

  public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("hello " + object);
    object.doThis();
  }

  public void doThis(){
    System.out.println("Did this");
  }
}
```

```
public class B extends A{
  B object;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    B b = new B();
    b.create();
  }

  public void create(){
    object = new B();
    object.doSomething();
  }
}
```

I understand that in Class A, the object is not actually created anywhere which is why it's probably null. I am wondering how can I make it so it's not.

Comment: Why does A have a field `object` of type A, and why does `B` hide that field with another field `object` of type `B`? Unless your modelling some form of linked lists, it is unlikely that instances of `A` should have a field referring to another instance of `A` (and same goes for `B`). What are you actually trying to do? That said, the canonical way would be to 1) make the field final, 2) define a constructor that accepts the value to populate the field, and 3) use `Objects.requireNonNull` or some other not null-check to enforce that the field is not null.

Comment: It's kind of like two different modes - I thought I needed the ```obj``` in both classes since there are methods in both of them that need it.

Comment: You don't, `B` is also an `A`, you can access methods and fields (assuming the right visibility modifiers) implicitly or through `this` (and in rare cases through `super`). E.g. in `A`, `doSomething()` should call `doThis()` or `this.doThis()`, not `object.doThis()`, and in `B`, `create()` should call `doSomething()` or `this.doSomething()`, not `object.doSomething()`, and you don't need the `object` field in either class.

Comment: the whole design is very vague and strange. Why does an instance of `A` contain another instance of `A`; why does an instance of `B` contain another instance of `B` (and, by inheritance another one of `A` too)?

Comment: In the program, the object is used and can either be an A or a B. The issue I am having is when it is a B and using A's methods, the object is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference an instance of the class within one of its methods, then use `this`.

If you want to make sure that a method in a super class keeps its original implementation and is never overridden by a subclass, then make it final.

If this isn't what you want, then I don't think what you are trying to do is actually practical.

```
public class A {
  public final void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("hello " + this);
    this.doThis();
  }

  public final void doThis(){
    System.out.println("Did this");
  }
}

public class B extends A{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    B b = new B();
    b.create();
  }

  public void create(){
    this.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to write the ```doSomething``` method again in B since it would be the same thing except with ```object``` being an instance of B rather than A

Comment: @Chjach `B` already has a `doSomething()` method, because `B` is a subclass of `A`, it inherits that method.

Comment: @Chjach Note how this answer calls `doSomething` on a B and it works fine. You don't need or want those `B object;` fields, and you don't need to copy doSomething over. perhaps review what object oriented _means_. `class B extends A` means that a B automatically has everything A has, and you are free to add more stuff too, but you don't have to. You __cant__ remove stuff.